# Get Facebook Wall Post using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

HI any one can help me to fetch the post the facebook page and display it in my web page

This is the url.
https://www.facebook.com/yakimonos

I have worked with facebook login and sent invitations to friends.
So i have some basic knowledge in working with the facebook sdk.

But i don't know how to proceed with this task.

So please help me.

thanks to all.

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve? The posts made by that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FQL to fetch posts of page. You will require `read_stream` permission.

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE  source_id = 'page_id' and actor_id = 'page_id'
```

For your page-

```
$fql = "SELECT message FROM stream WHERE  source_id = '183144838398839' and actor_id = '183144838398839'";
$posts = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
));

print_r($posts );
```